# How do I get onClick to work in my nested React Component?

Tags: reactjs

UPDATE: My code checked out just fine.  The issue was that a stopPropagation() was called in a separate Javascript library that prevented my onClicks from working.

--

I have a "MenuLink" react component in which I've added an onClick listener to an 'a' tag.  The "MenuLink" component is imported from a "MenuItem" component which is imported from a "MainMenu" component (see below).

When I click on link generated from MenuLink, nothing happens.  No errors, no nothing.  I would expect to see "handleClick" in my console and for the link to be prevented from executing.

**MenuLink.js**

```
class MenuLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = props.link;
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log("handleClick");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const link = this.state;

    return (
      <a
        href={link.alias}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {link.title}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuLink;
```

**MenuItem.js**

```
import MenuLink from './MenuLink.js';

class MenuItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.item;
  }

  render(key) {
    const item = this.state;

    return(
      <li
        key={key}
      >
        <MenuLink
          link={item}
        />

      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuItem;
```

**MainMenu.js**

```
import MenuItem from '../components/MenuItem.js';

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menu: []
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ul className="menu">
        {this.state.menu.map(function(menuItem, i) {
          return(
            <MenuItem key={i} item={menuItem} />
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/menu_items/main')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ menu: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet shows that it does work as expected. No changes were made.

```js
class MenuLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = props.link;
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log("handleClick");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const link = this.state;

    return (
      <a
        href={link.alias}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {link.title}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

class MenuItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.item;
  }

  render(key) {
    const item = this.state;
    
    console.log(key) // Undefined. Don't do this
    return(
      <li
        key={key}
      >
        <MenuLink
          link={item}
        />

      </li>
    );
  }
}

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menu: [{
      alias: 'test', 
      title: 'test'
    },
    {
      alias: 'test2', 
      title: 'test2'
    }]
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ul className="menu">
        {this.state.menu.map(function(menuItem, i) {
          return(
            <MenuItem key={i} item={menuItem} />
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainMenu />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Brian.  Do you think it matters that my MenuLink component is included within another component?  Could that be why it is not working for me?

Comment: Not sure, it's possible I guess. Are you seeing the link at all?

Comment: I'm seeing the link, but onClick does nothing.  I can see it works fine in your code snippet.  Thanks for adding that.

Comment: You can add the parent component to the question and we can see

Comment: I've added the parent component(s)

Comment: @briangervais I updated my answer, same thing. Still works as expected. Although now I will point out that `render` does not accept any arguements. `key` will always be undefined. The `key` only needs to be assigned to the highest tag within a loop. You don't need to use it in the middle component.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that key is unneeded.  I'm so confused why this is not working.  I can see it works perfectly in your example.

Comment: At this point I'd start debugging elsewhere. Things like making sure the app has been rebuilt (assuming you're using webpack or CRA or some other form of bundling). Console log everywhere and follow the flow and see if anything is strange. Remove the `onClick` handler and see if it changes pages. But we've ruled out that the problem is in this code.

Comment: So it turns out there was some JS in the theme for the project I'm working on that had a stopPropagation() method that was preventing my onClicks from working.

(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";

class MenuLink extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        // this.state = props.link;
        this.state = {
            link: {alias: "http://www.google.com", title: 'Google'}
        }
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        console.log("handleClick");
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {

        const link = this.state.link;

        return (
            <div>
                <a
                    href={link.alias}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                    {link.title}
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MenuLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work

```
class MenuLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = props.link;
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    console.log("handleClick");
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }

  render() {
    const link = this.state;

    return (
      <a
        href={link.alias}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {link.title}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuLink;
```

Comment: Its true they don't need to bind the function to `this`, but not calling `preventDefault()` will cause the page to change which is what they are trying to avoid. Neither of these things really contribute to solving the question though.